# Binding Paths of RadCartesianChart BarSeries PointTemplate

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, charts, telerik

I have the following bit of XAML:

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart x:Name="lifeChart" Grid.Row="1" Palette="Windows8">
            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis >
                <telerik:LinearAxis Maximum="200" Title="Average Life Span (seconds)"/>
            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                <telerik:CategoricalAxis />
            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
            <telerik:BarSeries ValueBinding="AvgLifetime" CategoryBinding="GamerTag" IsHitTestVisible="True">
                <telerik:BarSeries.PointTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding ConverterParameter=GamerTag, Converter={StaticResource chartColorConv}, Mode=OneWay}" Tag="{Binding Source=DeathCount,Path=GamerTag}" MouseLeftButtonUp="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp_1" Cursor="Hand" IsHitTestVisible="True" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:BarSeries.PointTemplate>

            </telerik:BarSeries>
        </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

The CategoryBinding and ValueBinding works fine (so I'm connected to my data right?) and the Fill binding semi-works (calls the converter but passes the string GamerTag as the parameter instead of the bound data), but the Tag binding does not work.  When I click on the rectangle and handle the click, the Tag is always null.

What could cause this?

Comment: I see that my DataContext for the Rectangle is different from the DataContext of my chart.  Instead of GamerTag for my Tag property binding, I can do Category and the proper value gets bound to the Rectangle's Tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the string "GamerTag" in the parameter for your Value Converter, because that is what you have passed to it. You cannot use Binding expressions on the ConverterParameter property and if you define that parameter in XAML, it will always be interpreted as a string.

If Binding `Tag` with `{Binding Path=Category}` does what you want and you want the same value for your converter, then you can make a similar change to your Binding on Fill.

```
<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Category, Converter={S...
```